# Is this a bug in the Intel Fortran compiler?

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran, compiler-bug

I have reproduced some strange behaviour I got when compiling some code with the Intel Fortran compiler ifort by making a minimal example. The strange behaviour also shows up with the newer Intel compiler ifx.

Compile the following code with either ifort version 2021.10.0 or ifx version 2023.2.0.

```
ifort minimal_example.f90
```

or

```
ifx minimal_example.f90
```

minimal_example.f90

```
subroutine f(n)
    implicit none
    integer,  intent(in) :: n
    real :: x(n)
    real :: y(n)
    real :: z(n)
    call g(z, y)

contains
    
    subroutine g(z, y)
        real, intent(in)  :: z(size(x))
        real, intent(out) :: y(n)
        print*, 'n       = ', n
        print*, 'size(y) = ', size(y)
    end subroutine
    
end subroutine
        

program minimal_example
    implicit none
    external f
    call f(8)
end program
```

I get the output:

```
 n       =            8
 size(y) =            0
```

With gfortran I get:

```
 n       =            8
 size(y) =            8
```

Is this a bug in the two Intel Fortran compilers?

If I replace size(x) with n, the strange behaviour goes away. But I think it should be valid to use size(x).

Comment: You've identified a perfectly reasonable workaround, so beyond "yes" what sort of answer are you after? Is there a particular part you are concerned may not be valid Fortran?

Comment: Should I report it to Intel?

Comment: By the way, another workaround is to swap the order of the dummy arguments in g. Are these really good workarounds or undefined behaviour from the bug?

Comment: You should report to Intel. Whether it's a bug in the compiler or not, though, if you want to use your code with those compilers, you'll need to modify the code: even a "yes it's a bug" answer here won't actually help you in that! (Although an MRE is good for reporting a bug, it's really not very good for working out alternatives: what's good in the minimal example may be terrible in the production code. One would (hopefully) never write real code like the MRE here, and simplifying the code removes the undesirable behaviour.)

Comment: Ok, thanks. Is it typical that highly optimizing compilers like ifort are somewhat buggy?

Comment: No, it is not. But compilers are very complex, and usages not typically seen might trigger bugs. Report it at https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Fortran-Compiler/bd-p/fortran-compiler

Comment: I have to disagree with @SteveLionel for once: Fortran is a very complicated language and I doubt there's a single compiler which is both useful and free of bugs. If you find one of the bugs in an Intel (or other) compiler you are lucky/unlucky, but it's hard to go through years of Fortran development without ever doing something crazy enough to catch a case not covered by one compiler vendor's internal test suite. (I don't keep count of how many bugs I've reported.)

Comment: I took issue with "somewhat buggy". I did support for Intel Fortran (and DEC/Compaq Fortran) for many years and was also a developer. Yes, there were bugs, but almost always for strange combinations of features or usages. New features in the language tended to be worse off initially.

Comment: I rarely use “contains”, unless it is a module, and an “IMPLICIT NONE” in “subroutine g” would not hurt. And I would likely print out SIZE(X) and SIZE(Z). I did not even know one could have a subroutine contain a subroutine, and not just be terminates with “RETURN” and “END SUBROUTINE”… so I probably follow a style that is more old school.

Comment: I use internal procedures to avoid having so long argument lists. Implicit none is inherited from f to g.